# I am not able to populate the item in cart router. The item is the instance of ItemModel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to populate **item** in cart routes but I am not able to populate. I am not able to populate the item in the cart router. The item is the instance of ItemModel.

***ItemModel.js***

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    subtaskItemName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
    subtaskItemImage: {
        type: String
    },
    subtaskItemTime: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    subtaskItemPrice: {
        type: String
    },
    subtaskItemStatus: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    subtask: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'SubTask',
        required: true
    },
    createdAT: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Item", ItemSchema);
```

***CartModel.js***

```
const monngose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = monngose.Schema;

const CartSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    task_items: [{
        task_item: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SubTaskCategoryItem'},
        quantity: { type: Number, default: 1 }

    }],
    totalPrice: {
        type: Number
    },
    item: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Item'
    },
    crreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
module.exports = monngose.model('Cart', CartSchema);
```

***CartRoute.js***

```
const express = require('express');
const Cart = require('../../models/admin/CartModel');
const checkJwt = require('../../middleware/admin/user_auth');
const TaskItem = require('../../models/admin/ItemModel');

const router = express.Router();
  router.get('/get_cart', checkJwt, (req, res, next) => {

    Cart.find({ user:  req.user.id })
      .populate({
        path: 'user'
      })
      .populate('item')
    .exec((err, cart) => {
      res.json({
        msg: 'User not exists',
        cart: cart
      });

    })
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

How to populate the **item** field in cart.js router. I want to populate items in cart routes but I am not able to populate. I am not able to populate the item in the cart router. The item is the instance of ItemModel

Answer (score 0):

I the task_item under task_items array id the item id.

```
  {
        "msg": "User not exists",
        "cart": [
            {
                "_id": "5ec0c28cf494113aa06c99d9",
                "task_items": [
                    {
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "_id": "5ec0c28cf494113aa06c99da",
                        "task_item": "5ebe499d7e657d322c39345f"
                    },
                    {
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "_id": "5ec0d018ecc2411cf40bceae",
                        "task_item": "5ebe499d7e657d322c39345f"
                    },
                    {
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "_id": "5ec0d4abfac25246689d15a7",
                        "task_item": "5ec0d4a2fac25246689d15a6"
                    }
                ],
                "crreated": "2020-05-17T04:50:20.869Z",
                "user": {
                    "_id": "5ebe4d5d440ab504c8a0d128",
                    "name": "Ajit",
                    "phone": "9668854799",
                    "avatar": "//www.gravatar.com/avatar/20c3d59b7049c9ad85cd33e2ebd3151c?s=200&r=pg&d=mm",
                    "password": "$2a$10$FdH7QzoqOHnVoLbbm9GaUOLaJbTTqPWzFWeFACkea2NWlrJrFxZ5a",
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-15T08:05:49.418Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "__v": 2
            }
        ]
    }
```